# I get System.InvalidCastException, when retrieving a dictionary from Session state

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception

> [A]System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[DisplayAllQuestionsTable]]
>   cannot be cast to
>   [B]System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[DisplayAllQuestionsTable]].
>   Type A originates from 'mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' in
>   the context 'LoadNeither' at location

My Dictionary syntax:

```
Dictionary<string, List<DisplayAllQuestionsTable>> tPages=tPages = 
   new Dictionary<string, List<DisplayAllQuestionsTable>>();
```

When i try to retrieve it from Session:

```
tPages = (Dictionary<string, List<DisplayAllQuestionsTable>>)Session["ThreadPage"]; // i get an exception here

Unable to cast object of type [
```

> **`System.String`**

,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[DisplayAllQuestionsTable]]' to type '**System.Collection**s.Generic.Dictionary`2

Comment: check whether you are casting the correct session variable

Comment: If you save just a single instance of DisplayAllQuestionsTable in Session can it be retrieved without an exception?

Comment: hmmm..but i need to cast teh whole dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get the type of the Session["ThreadPage"] object:

```
Session["ThreadPage"].GetType().ToString();
```

Comment: +1 for teaching `Matrix001` some debugging skills. We are all going to die. But first we must debug!

Comment: System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[DisplayAllQuestionsTable]] Thats what i get in the string..how is that helpful?

Comment: see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx, especially the section that states :When you use a session-state mode other than InProc, the session-variable type must be either a primitive .NET type or serializable. This is because the session-variable value is stored in an external data store. For more information.  So I think you need to ensure that the DisplayAllQuestionsTable class is serializable.

Comment: This wont work:   [Serializable()]  
    public class DisplayAllQuestionsTable  and it says that it cants convert string type to Dictionary type. See the full message above.. i updated

Comment: try to set the Serializable attribute on all custom classes, if any, that the DisplayAllQuestionsTable is using.

Comment: Idea on how i can serialize DisplayAllQuestionsTable"

Comment: it hasnt worked yet..:(..                                              i get some new error: [A]System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[myNamspace.DisplayAllQuestionsTable]] cannot be cast to [B]System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[myNamspace.DisplayAllQuestionsTable]]. Type A originates from 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' in the context 'LoadNeither' at location 'D:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Ne

Comment: why can i put a list of buttons without it being serializable??!? the Session of a list doesnt through an exception!!

Comment: @Matrix001: Please try to avoid swearing here, and try to avoid multiple punctuation marks!!!!?!?!?!?!(!)!!?!?!!)!(!)!(!!)!?!?!?!!---......1.11111elevenone. Get my point?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have two different `DisplayAllQuestionsTable` versions of this type?

Qualify the `DisplayAllQuestionsTable` type name with namespace.

Ex:

```
// Creating the instance..
Dictionary<string, List<SampleAppNamespace.DisplayAllQuestionsTable>> tPages = 
   new Dictionary<string, List<SampleAppNamespace.DisplayAllQuestionsTable>>();

// putting it into session
Session["ThreadPage"] = tPages;

// reading back from session
tPages = Session["ThreadPage"] as Dictionary<string, List<SampleAppNamespace.DisplayAllQuestionsTable>>;
```

Comment: How do i do that qualification. DisplayAllQuestionsTable..is simply a class that i have on my page..there are no other classes that i have.. Do you want me to make a new namespace.. like myNameSpace.DisplayAllQuestionsTable??

Comment: tPages = (Dictionary<string, List<myNamspace.DisplayAllQuestionsTable>>)Session["ThreadPage"];    tPages = new Dictionary<string, List<myNamspace.DisplayAllQuestionsTable>>(); ---wont work